# Pytest ETL Unit testing

Tags: python, unit-testing, etl, pytest

My requirement is do ETL testing through python pytest module.

I pass a job name into the pytest script and script will test for four table load testing using a for loop.

I have below two issues -

1. I am not able to pass command line argument in the pytest script.
2. Though I written a for loop inside which pytest test functions are present. But my test scripts are not running for fours tables , it's only running for one table and coming out of the loop and showing the results.

Any help in this regard would be helpful.

Comment: 1. Do you mean your tests expects a command line argument? If so why not adding them directly to `sys.argv`. 2. Please post the relevant code. See how to create a [mcve]

Comment: don't use a for loop inside a test, use the `@pytest.mark.parametrize` decorator.

Comment: please post your code